# Calling C++ library with Python 2.7 and Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, c++11, swig, boost-python

I have a large performance sensitive library written in C++11 with variadic templates and model classes. This is a header only C++ library.

I want to write the Python bindings for this library.

The python bindings should support Python 2.7 and Python 3.x.

My problem is I am not finding a way to create bindings between C++ and Python. I did see references to Boost.Python and SWIG, however, I could not find anything that clearly identified how to create the bindings between C++ and Python.

What is the simplest, clearest, step-by-step method of creating a binding?

Comment: It's a shame that this was closed as "too broad" without even so much as a comment or answer to direct OP elsewhere.  I had a similar question.  From my searching, it seems that many people find SWIG to be prohibitively confusing, and Boost.Python has no update for some years.  ctypes (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ctypes.html)  seems to be a popular choice which I will try.

Comment: Nominated this for opening, I don't think it's "too broad".  Answers should explain why this is a large, non-trivial task, and possible scenarios to solve it, either with swig, cffi, and/or a custom binding generated using clang.